# Is there a way to reference the dataframe subset being changed with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code bellow, but i'm not sure is the best way to write it. Is there a better way to reference the dataframe selecion I am attributing the changes to?

```
df.VALUE[df.GROUP == 'A'] = np.where(df.CLASSE[df.GROUP == 'A'] == 'C', 0, df.VALUE[df.GROUP == 'A'])
```

Comment: Try... `df['VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].mask((df['CLASSE'] == 'C') & (df['GROUP'] == 'A'),0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you should avoid in any case is to use **chained assignments** (this is specifically discouraged in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html)), you should instead use `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df.GROUP == 'A', 'VALUE'] = np.where(df.loc[df.GROUP == 'A', 'CLASSE'] == 'C', 0, 
                                            df.loc[df.GROUP == 'A', 'VALUE'])
```